# p:fileUpload response returns before actionListener method ended in backing bean

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with Primefaces 5.2 fileUpload actionListener in a JSF 2.2 application. Below is an example of code:

```
<h:form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <h:panelGroup id="fileUploader">
                    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadControllerBean.handleFileUpload}"
                                  onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();"
                                  oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide();"
                                  mode="advanced"
                                  dragDropSupport="false"
                                  multiple="false"
                                  update="form1:uploadMessagesGrowl,
                                    :form2:fileUploadMessage,
                                    :form3:fileUploadPanelGroup"
                                  uploadLabel="#{common['validateFileStudents']}"
                                  label="#{common['addFileStudents']}"
                                  cancelLabel="#{common['cancelFileStudents']}"
                                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/"/>

                    <p:growl id="uploadMessagesGrowl" showDetail="true" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
```

I need to upload a file and handle it in actionListener (parse, validate to actual data, etc.). After that the button 'Insert' on the 3rd form should be rendered if file is valid and no data from this file exists in database. When there is a small amount of data in the file - all is OK. But when there is a big amount of data - response returns before all data in file validated(before actionListener method ended). This leading to potential mistake when bad data in the end of file and validates after response is sended.

I think, i can do this in another way - just add validation button and validate file after upload, but i want to use fileUpload actionlistener for upload and validation at the same time.

Anybody have an idea why response returns before actionListener method ended?

Comment: You could set the rendered attribute of the "Insert" button at the end of your actionListener-method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:form3:fileUploadPanelGroup` from the `update` parameter and update the component at the end of your actionListener().

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":form3:fileUploadPanelGroup");`

Comment: It will be a good solution if response returns after actionListener completed. But response returns before backing bean method completed and before RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update() method invoked.